# For a martingale $\{Z_n,n\geq1\}$, let $X_i=Z_i-Z_{i-1},i\geq1$, where $Z_0\equiv0$. Show that $Var(Z_n)=\sum^n_{i=1}Var(X_i)$.

Tags: probability, martingales, variance

For a martingale $\{Z_n,n\geq1\}$, let $X_i=Z_i-Z_{i-1},i\geq1$, where $Z_0\equiv0$. Show that $$Var(Z_n)=\sum^n_{i=1}Var(X_i)$$

If $\{Z_n\}$ is a martingale, then $E[Z_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k]=Z_k$ for a filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$. I'm really not sure about how to start this problem. Could I get some hints about which properties of martingales to use? Thank you.

Comment: Then formula is not correct. Perahps you have switched some symbols.

Comment: I think there is this formula for martingales $E[(Z_n-Z_{n-1})^2]=E[Z_n^2-Z_{n-1}^2]$, which could be useful. Try to prove this first.

Comment: Also ask yourself, what $E[Z_n-Z_{n-1}]$ and $E[Z_0]^2$ are. Combining my hints will lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
Var(X_i)&=Var(Z_i-Z_{i-1})\\
&=E[(Z_i-Z_{i-1}-E[Z_i-Z_{i-1}])^2]\\
&=E[(Z_i-Z_{i-1})^2]\\
&=E[Z_i^2-Z_{i-1}^2]
\end{align}
$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n E[Z_i^2-Z_{i-1}^2] = E[Z_n^2]$$

Using $E[Z_n]=0$, it holds

$$\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) = E[Z_n^2] - E[Z_n]^2 = Var(Z_n)$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got to $E[(Z_i-Z_{i-1}-E[Z_i-Z_{i-1}])^2]$ in the second line?

Comment: The definition of variance is $Var(X)=E[(X-E[X])^2]$. Applying to $X=Z_i-Z_{i-1}$, yields $Var(Z_i-Z_{i-1})=E[(Z_i-Z_{i-1}-E[Z_i-Z_{i-1}])^2]$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,  $Z_0=0$ and $Z_n =  X_1 + \dots + X_n,~n=1,2,\dots$. By the Martingale property,
$E[X_n |{\cal F}_{n-1}]=0$ for all $n=1,2,\dots$.

Now:

1. $\mbox{Var}(Z_n)=E[Z_n^2]$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$.
2. $E[Z_0^2]=0$ and for  $n=1,2,\dots$, we have the following formula, mentioned in an different, but equivalent form  in the  comment made by @user408858
   \begin{align*} 
   (*)\quad E[Z_n^2|{\cal F}_{n-1}]  & =E[(Z_{n-1} +X_n)^2 |{\cal F}_{n-1}] \\
    & = Z_{n-1}^2 +2E[X_n|{\cal F}_{n-1}] Z_{n-1} +X_n^2  \\
   & = Z_{n-1}^2 + 0+ X_n^2.
   \end{align*}
   Taking expectations on both sides of $(*)$ gives
   $$\mbox{Var}(Z_n) = \mbox{Var}(Z_{n-1}) + E[X_n^2],$$
   and so
   $$\mbox{Var}(Z_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n E[X_k^2].$$